# Как редактировать .dll файл в кодировке ANSI без искажений содержимых символов?

Tags: c#, кодировка, dll, ansi

Мне необходимо поменять числовое значение в .dll файле, не трогая остальное содержимое, либо перезаписывая содержимое без изменений.

После выполнения моего кода, редактируемый файл увеличивается в размерах с 60мб до 90, при этом теряя некоторые символы, похожие на заглюченную кириллицу. Я пытался использовать `Encoding.Default`, это помогло лишь для сохранения символов `\0`, кириллица по прежнему стирается/превращается в неизвестные символы, увеличивая размер файла.

Мой код редактирует файл подобным образом:

```c#
static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                var line = File.ReadLines("client.dll").ToArray();

                foreach (var i in line)
                {
                    if (i.Contains("1200"))
                    {
                        Console.Write("Введите новое значение: "); 
                        var newValue = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())
                        
                        var newText = i.Replace("1200", newValue); 
                        LineChanger(newText, "client.dll", 317440);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ошибка!: " + e.Message);
            }
        }

        private static void LineChanger(string newText, string fileName, int lineToEdit)
        {
            string[] arrLine = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
            arrLine[lineToEdit - 1] = newText;
            File.WriteAllLines(fileName, arrLine, Encoding.Default);
        }
```

Как я могу отредактировать файл, что бы он перезаписался без потерь?

Comment: С dll нужно работать не как с текстом, а как с байтами

Comment: То есть перед редактированием мне следует поместить это всё в массив байтов, отредактировать байты после чего вытащить это всё в исходное состояние?

Comment: Именно. Всё правильно понимаете. Кроме того, вам ещё повезло, что хватило памяти, потому что строки в C# - неизменяемые и вот такое создание копии в цикле приводит к беуздержному росту в памяти строк.

Comment: [ReadAllBytes](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readallbytes?view=net-5.0) / [WriteAllBytes](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writeallbytes?view=net-5.0) или [FileStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525660) в помощь (наверное)

Comment: Понял, попробую редактировать содержимое через байты, спасибо за ответы!

Comment: Что из себя представляет эта dll? Что внутри неё, код на каком языке программирования?

Comment: Обычная dll из файлов игры, внутри неё судя по всему скомпилированный код (я не уверен), иногда встречаются строки файлов с расширением .cpp
Наполнен символами NUL (\0) и "кривой" кириллицей вперемешку с цифрами и обычными символами (те же названия файлов, например "something.cpp")
Мой код на c#

Comment: Обратите внимание, при редактировании двоичного исполняемого файла вы не можете изменить его длину, то есть вы не можете например поменять `1200` на `125`, но можете на `1234`, то есть только замена байт, добавлять и удалять нельзя.

Comment: Редактируя файл с данной целью - вы не можете увеличить размер строки, из-за команд перехода на адрес для выполнения, всё просто сдвинется, уменьшать тоже не желательно, но если вы уменьшаете - есть следующие варианты: 1) добавить пробелы, 2) добавить 0x00 вместо каждого неиспользуемого места символа (ABCDEF x00 -> ABC x00000000), 3) добавить 0x00 вместо первого неиспользуемого символа, а после заполнить 0x90 (NOP), например: ABCDEF x00 -> ABC x00909090. Гарантировано должен сработать первый вариант, остальные на правах идеи.